# fzf output to xdotool instead of the terminal

Tags: xdotool, dmenu, fzf

I can create a `fzf.sh` script to launch a list of items, allow me to select an item, and print the output of the specific line selected to the terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ~/list.txt | fzf --reverse
```

I created an Ubuntu keyboard shortcut to launch this script utilizing the following command:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "fzf.sh"'
```

I'm trying to determine how can I get the selected line to print to the application I have in focus, instead of the terminal, when I initiate the keyboard shortcut.

I've done this before with dmenu and xdotool in the following manner with my `dmenu.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool sleep 0.3 type --delay 0.1 "$(grep -v '^#' ~/list.txt | dmenu | cut -f1)"
```

Then the output is spit into whatever program I have open (e.g. Chrome).

How can I do the same with fzf? This script below doesn't work, I think the output of the line selected is getting printed to a phantom terminal, because I can select a line from `list.txt` and see a terminal pop up quickly (then close) but nothing is printed to my application in focus like used to occur with dmenu:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool sleep 0.3 type --delay 0.1 "$(grep -v '^#' ~/list.txt | fzf --reverse | cut -f1)"
```

I'm trying to move away from dmenu and towards fzf (or an alternative) becuase I'm having display issues and will need to start utilizing Ubuntu's default Wayland session.